# Как можно улучшить код к лучшему?

Tags: javascript, jquery, инспекция-кода

*улучшить* - читабельность, модульность, производительность. В фронте не силен. Условие: чистый js либо jQuery. Единственная модульность - у каждой вьюшки свой js (MVC на сервере). 
Пример кода js одной из `view`:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    let ExpenseContents = [];
    let sum = 0;
    let CreatedDate = new Date();
    // Клик на добавить содержимое расхода
    jQuery("#btnAddingExpenseToTable").click(function () {
        let num = 0;
        ExpenseContents.push({
            code: $(this).parent().parent().find("#inputExpenseCode").val(),
            product: { Id: $(this).parent().parent().find("#selected_product").val(), Title: $(this).parent().parent().find("#selected_product option")[$(this).parent().parent().find("#selected_product")[0].selectedIndex].innerHTML },
            count: $(this).parent().parent().find("#inputExpenseCount").val(),
            price: $(this).parent().parent().find("#inputExpensePrice").val(),
            sum: $(this).parent().parent().find("#inputExpenseCount").val() * $(this).parent().parent().find("#inputExpensePrice").val()
        });
        let index = ExpenseContents.length - 1;
        let currentExpense = ExpenseContents[index];
        jQuery("#tableExpenses").append("<div class='row my-2'><div class='col idExpense'>" +index +"</div><div class='col'>" + currentExpense.code + "</div><div class= 'col'>" + currentExpense.product.Title + "</div><div class='col'>" + currentExpense.count + "</div><div class='col'>" + currentExpense.price + "</div><div class='col'>" + currentExpense.sum + "</div><div class='col text-center'><button class='btn btn-block btn-outline-warning' id='btnUpdatingExpenseInTable'>Изменить</button></div><div class='col text-center'><button class='btn btn-block btn-outline-danger' id='btnDeleteExpenseInTable'>Удалить</button></div></div>");
        ExpenseContents.forEach(function (el) {
            sum += el.sum;
        });
        console.log(sum);
        jQuery("#amountExpense").text(sum.toString());
    });
    // Клик по кнопке "провести"
    jQuery("#btnExpenseHold").click(function () {
        requestToExpense(new Date, CreatedDate, jQuery("#selected_client").val(), sum, 1, new Date(), ExpenseContents);
    });
    // Клик по кнопке "отложить"
    jQuery("#btnExpenseDelayed").click(function () {
        requestToExpense(new Date, CreatedDate, jQuery("#selected_client").val(), sum, 0, null, ExpenseContents);
    });
    // Клик по кнопке "отменить"
    jQuery("#btnExpenseCanseled").click(function () {
        requestToExpense(new Date, CreatedDate, jQuery("#selected_client").val(), sum, 2, null, ExpenseContents);
    });
    // Клик по кнопке "очистить"
    jQuery("#btnClearEditCol").click(function () {
        $(this).parent().parent().find("input").each(function () {
           $(this).val("");
        });
    });
    // Клик по кнопке "изменить"
    jQuery("#btnUpdatingExpenseInTable").click(function () {
        $(this).parent().parent().parent().find(".update-row").each(function () {
            $(this).css("display", "block");
        }).end().parent().parent().parent().find(".view-row").each(function () {
            $(this).css("display", "none");
        });
    });
    // Клик по кнопке "сохранить"
    jQuery("#btnSaveUpdatingExpenseInTable").click(function () {
        console.log($(this).parent().parent().parent().find(".idExpense").text()); //id!!!
        // изменить id^ в массиве >>>>> ExpenseContents по $(this)
    });

});

/// Вносим в БД расход и его содержимое
function requestToExpense(date, dateCreate, clientId, sum, status, dateSpeading,mass) {
    let data = JSON.stringify({ Date: date, ClientId: clientId, Sum: sum, ExpenseCreated: dateCreate, ExpenseStatus: status, TimeSpeadingExpense: dateSpeading });
    jQuery.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        crossDomain: true,
        url: "https://localhost:44334/Data/Expense/Create",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        data: data,
        processData: false,
        success: function (res) {
            let contents = [];

            mass.forEach(function (el) {
                contents.push({ Code: el.code, ProductId: el.product.Id, Count: el.count, Price: el.price, Sum: el.sum, ExpenseId: res });
            });

            let data2 = JSON.stringify({ contents });
            jQuery.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                crossDomain: true,
                url: "https://localhost:44334/Data/Contents/Create",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                data: data2,
                processData: false,
                success: function (res) {

                },
                Error: function () {
                }
            });
        },
        Error: function () {
        }
    });
}
```

Приму любые предложения по улучшению данного кода, спасибо :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно улучшить:

- Избавиться от конструкций вида `$(this).parent().parent()`. Если поменяется верстка, то будет тяжело это менять, плюс потенциальные баги.
- Заменить обработчики кнопок вида `jQuery("#btnExpenseHold").click(function () {...` на единый. Необходимые данные хранить в `data-*` атрибутах.
- Вызов двух АПИ в `requestToExpense` слить один. На самом деле спорный момент. С одной стороны нарушаем принцип единой ответственности. С другой стороны, если у вас выполнится `Expense/Create` но не выполнится `Contents/Create` данные могут быть в неконсистентном состоянии.
- Создать свои методы для **POST, PUT, GET, DELETE**, что бы можно было обрабатывать в ошибки в одном месте, хранить `url` до АПИ тоже в одном месте.
- Придерживаться единого стиля в названиях переменных. Стандартом де-факто для JS является `camelCase`.
- Также везде использовать что-то одно. Или `$` или `JQuery`.
- Не писать конструкции вида `$('.smth').append('<div>'+someText+'</div>')`. Чревато ошибками, если в `someText` будут спецсимволы.

Код с учетом всех изменений

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  let ExpenseContents = [];
  let sum = 0;
  let CreatedDate = new Date();
  // Клик на добавить содержимое расхода
  $("#btnAddingExpenseToTable").click(function() {
    let num = 0;
    const $form = $('#create-form');
    const formVal = (selector) => {
      return $form.find(selector).val()
    };
    ExpenseContents.push({
      code: formVal("#inputExpenseCode"),
      product: {
        Id: formVal("#selected_product"),
        Title: $form.find("#selected_product option")[$form.find("#selected_product")[0].selectedIndex].innerHTML
      },
      count: formVal("#inputExpenseCount"),
      price: formVal("#inputExpensePrice"),
      sum: formVal("#inputExpenseCount") * formVal("#inputExpensePrice")
    });
    let index = ExpenseContents.length - 1;
    let currentExpense = ExpenseContents[index];

    const row = $('#example_row').clone();
    const setRowText = (selector, value) => {
      row.find(selector).text(value);
    };
    setRowText('.idExpense', index);
    setRowText('.code', currentExpense.code);
    setRowText('.title', currentExpense.product.Title);
    setRowText('.count', currentExpense.count);
    setRowText('.price', currentExpense.price);
    setRowText('.sum', currentExpense.sum);

    $("#tableExpenses").append(row);

    ExpenseContents.forEach(function(el) {
      sum += el.sum;
    });
    console.log(sum);
    $("#amountExpense").text(sum.toString());
  });

  // Клик по кнопкам
  $(".btn-action").click(function() {
    const $button = $(this);
    requestToExpense(new Date, CreatedDate, $("#selected_client").val(), sum, $(this).data('status'), new Date($(this).data('time')) || null, ExpenseContents);
  });

  // Клик по кнопке "изменить"
  $("#btnUpdatingExpenseInTable").click(function() {
    $('.row-id').find(".update-row").each(function() {
      $(this).css("display", "block");
    })
    $('.another-id').find(".view-row").each(function() {
      $(this).css("display", "none");
    });
  });
  // Клик по кнопке "сохранить"
  $("#btnSaveUpdatingExpenseInTable").click(function() {
    console.log($(this).parent().parent().parent().find(".idExpense").text()); //id!!!
    // изменить id^ в массиве >>>>> ExpenseContents по $(this)
  });


  /// Вносим в БД расход и его содержимое
  function requestToExpense(date, dateCreate, clientId, sum, status, dateSpeading, mass) {
    let data = {
      Date: date,
      ClientId: clientId,
      Sum: sum,
      ExpenseCreated: dateCreate,
      ExpenseStatus: status,
      TimeSpeadingExpense: dateSpeading
    };
    data.contents = [];
    mass.forEach(function(el) {
      data.contents.push({
        Code: el.code,
        ProductId: el.product.Id,
        Count: el.count,
        Price: el.price,
        Sum: el.sum
      });
    });
    POST('ExpenseContents/Create', data, (res) => {});
  }

});

// This variable should be defined in a separate file.
const API = "https://localhost:44334/Data/";

// This function should be defined in a separate file.
function POST(url, data, success, error) {
  return $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    crossDomain: true,
    url: API + url,
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    data: data,
    success: success,
    error: function() {
      console.log('this is standard error handler');
      error && error();
    }
  });
}
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="example_row" class='hidden row my-2'>
  <div class='col idExpense'></div>
  <div class='col code'></div>
  <div class='col title'></div>
  <div class='col count'></div>
  <div class='col price'></div>
  <div class='col' sum></div>
  <div class='col text-center'><button class='btn btn-block btn-outline-warning' id='btnUpdatingExpenseInTable'>Изменить</button></div>
  <div class='col text-center'><button class='btn btn-block btn-outline-danger' id='btnDeleteExpenseInTable'>Удалить</button></div>
</div>
```

Comment: @ВиталийШебаниц спасибо принимается в виде принятого ответа)

Comment: Возможно будут ещё мнения по доработке